# Doctrine Events best practise?

Tags: php, events, doctrine-orm

After reading [THIS](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events) part of the **Doctrine documentation** which states that a **DQL** update Statement does **NOT** trigger the **preUpdate** or **postUpdate** *Event* I am totaly confused.

I **implemented Doctrine** into my own Application ... so no **Symfony** or whatsoever and everything works just great - and I am proud that I made it this far. **BUT .....**

How can I achieve to fetch all **pre** or **post** **Update** and **Flush** Events no matter if I used a custom **DQL** or one of these predefined **findOneBy()** and so forth methods ????

For now I would need them only for testing and **implementing the Caching system** since I dont have any complicated Entity Associations right now which require further persistence managment.

something like

```
<!--code start -->
// $key = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI.'_'.$entity
onPostUpdateEvent($memcached->delete($key));
if($memcached->get($key)){
    return $memcached->get($key);
}
$result = $em->getRepository($entity);
$memcached->set($key,$result,$lifetime);
return $result;
```

Actually I wanted to **setup a Custom Event Class to handle all events** or is it better to use the @preFoo and so on Annotations for functions inside the Entity ??

Is there a best practise for all cases ?

**EDIT:**

will try and use $query->resultCache();

for example:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('bla di bla');  
// doNotCache isset via EventListener listening to postUpdate
// in AbstractController initialize() Method
if($this->doNotCache){
    $query->useResultCache(false);
}else{  
   $query->useResultCache(true, 3600, 'my_custom_id'); 
}
$result = $query->getArrayResult();
```

Thank you so much